# how to append two dataframes with headings to CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes and have to append the data with headings into a csv or create a table in email body .

```
df1
Rowcount  Errorcode
5         1111
10        3456
12        2222
1         5555


df2
Rowcount  Errorcode
5         1111
10        3456
```

the data that goes to csv will look like :

```
The Errors in df1 are:
        Rowcount  Errorcode
        5         1111
        10        3456
        12        2222
        1         5555
    
The Errors in df2 are:
        
        Rowcount  Errorcode
        5         1111
        10        3456
```

I tried tabulate but it does not give a neat and nice formatted table in email body . It looks too clustered and not readable.

I would like to send a email notification with errors preferabbly email body with below details , if it does not work then even an attachment with below information would do.
I can send an email with attachment but i do not udnerstand how to append two dataframes data into single csv in below format.

Any help is appreciated!

My email api looks like this

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
import configparser
from smtplib import SMTP

filename = r'D:\folder\bin\PythonScripts\Config.ini'
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(filename)

smtp_server = config['Notification']['smtp_server']

def send_mail(subject, html, sender, recipients,csv_file_path,csv_file):
    # Create a multipart message
    message = MIMEMultipart("mixed")
    message['Subject'] = subject
    message['From'] = sender
    message['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
    # Add body to email
    #part1 = MIMEText(text, "plain")
    part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")

    #message.attach(part1)
    message.attach(part2)
    # open and read the CSV file in binary
    with open(csv_file_path,'rb') as file:
    # Attach the file with filename to the email
        message.attach(MIMEApplication(file.read(), Name=csv_file))
    


    with SMTP(smtp_server) as smtp:
        smtp.sendmail(sender, recipients, message.as_string())
```

How do I get a nice formatted table in a email body?

Comment: Can you append a `frame_name`? An attach the file as attachment.
Format:
`FrameName, Rowcount, Errorcode`

Comment: so you are saying instead of header , just put another column to say which dataframe , right ? yes i think i can do that.. and just concatenate these two.. thats a good idea . thanks Akhil.. also, any idea on how to get this in email body ??

Comment: yes an additional column.
[SMTPLIB](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) is one the libraries you can leverage.

Comment: You didn't give any context on how you plan to send the mail, you should provide minimal code, the question is currently not focused enough

Comment: @mozway.. sorry for late reply. I have attached my email API